# Model not being passed to controller

Tags: asp.net-core

One of my asp.net core pages isn't passing its model back to the controller. I've investigated similar threads in stackoverflow but none could solve my issue - what's different in this particular case?

In the attached MVC, I fill the input box "Enter here some text", then I click on button "CLICK HERE". The debugger enters correctly the controller but the variable "TEST" returns null.

Any geniuses out there able to help me out?

My Model:

```
namespace MyProgram.Models._04_ModuleTasker
{
    public class TaskerViewModel
    {
        public SelectList SelectListLocations;
        public SelectList SelectListUsers;
        public SelectList SelectListFilters;

        public string SelectedCompanyLocationDesc;
        public string SelectedUserId;
        public string SelectedFilter;

    }
}
```

My View:

```
@model MyProgram.Models._04_ModuleTasker.TaskerViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "AllTasks";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="PageTitle">
        Tasker
        <hr class="TitleHR" />
    </div>
    <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:20px" class="text-body">
        <form asp-controller="Tasker" asp-action="ShowActiveTasksPOST" method="post" role="form">
            <input type="text" asp-for="SelectedUserId" /> Enter here some text <br />
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success InputShortWidth LoginButton" value="CLICK HERE" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ShowActiveTasksPOST(TaskerViewModel taskerViewModel)
        {
            string TEST = taskerViewModel.SelectedUserId;         
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
```

Comment: What does the generated html for the form look like?

Comment: You are not passing model from your controller to view.

Comment: Aleksa - What should I change to pass the model to view?

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53882985/how-to-make-datetime-bind-to-razorpages-viewmodel/53887441#53887441 you have the same issue, you need a `setter and getter`

Comment: Hameed - that's it. Thanks a lot, got me stuck for a whole day and it was something as simple as that. Answer the question and I'll note it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the binding works, you need to convert the `fields` to `properties` with with  setters and getters. E.g.:

```cs
public string SelectedCompanyLocationDesc { get; set; }
public string SelectedUserId { get; set; }
public string SelectedFilter { get; set; }
```